# VSCode Intellisense options have to be clicked unless I hit ctrl+space. Tab and Enter not working although enabled

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

The Intellisense window in VSCode is popping up suggestions without highlighting anything in the pop-up.  Sometimes the suggestion window just pops up for a split second and closes itself immediately, also.  This just started happening today as far as I've noticed.  I can't select any of the suggestions unless I click on them.  Tab closes the suggestion window and inserts a tab into my code.  Enter also closes the suggestion window and inserts a newline into my code.  The arrow keys also close the suggestion then move my cursor around in my code.  If I hit ctrl+space while the suggestion window is showing or to trigger the suggestion window, the normal highlight shows in the suggestion window, tab or enter will insert the suggestion, and I can use arrow keys to move the highlighted suggestion like I'd expect.

[Intellisense suggestions not highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Can0o.png)

This is happening in an html file if I add an attribute and then an equal sign which auto-adds quotation marks which should contain a value e.g. type="".  As soon as I press the equal key, it adds the quotation marks and the suggestion window flashes and closes.  If I then start typing something between those quotation marks, an option displays in the intellisense suggestion window pop-up, but it can't be selected without clicking on it or hitting ctrl+space.  This isn't the only time it happens, just an example.  It also seems to be happening more frequently over time.
I tried disabling all extensions and re-installing VSCode but the behavior persists.

As asked by a commenter:
settings.json pasted below.
I tried removing everything and just leaving "{}" in settings.json.  I also tried just removing the line that says - "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue", - This made no difference.

OS is Windows 10 with all updates installed.

VS Code version:
Version: 1.75.1 (user setup)
Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Date: 2023-02-08T21:32:34.589Z
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: No

I tried uninstalling all of my extensions.  This made no difference.

settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
    "[html]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "[jsonc]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.linkedEditing": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "[typescript]": {
      "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
  
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  
      "titleBar.activeBackground": "#000000",
      "titleBar.border": "#646464",
      "activityBar.background": "#000000",
      "menu.background": "#000000",
      "editor.background": "#000000",
      "sideBar.background": "#000000",
      "peekViewEditor.background": "#111111",
      "peekView.border": "#646464",
      "peekViewTitle.background": "#272727"
  },
  
  "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true,
  
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned",
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.suggest.preview": true,
  "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
  "typescript.experimental.tsserver.web.enableProjectWideIntellisense": true
}
```

Comment: show the settings.json for a [mre]. Remove all settings not necessary to reproduce the issue. What OS are you on? What VS Code version are you on? What extensions need to be enabled for the issue to reproduce?